# Connecting python 3.3 to microsoft sql server 2008

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, python-3.x, pydev

I am new to python. I am using Pydev IDE with Eclipse for python programming in my Windows machine. I am using python 3.3 vern and want to connect with MS Sql Server 2008. Could someone suggest how should I connect with MS Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) supports python3 and can connect to any databas for wich there's an odbc driver, including sql server.

There's also a pure python implementation [pypyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) which also should supoort python3.

[adodbapi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adodbapi) also claims to work with python3.

[Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server) you can find a list with some more options.

Answer (score 10):

I will augment mata's answer with a pypyodbc example.

```
import pypyodbc
connection_string ='Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=<YOURSERVER>;Database=<YOURDATABASE>;Uid=<YOURUSER>;Pwd=<YOURPASSWORD>;'
connection = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM <YOURTABLE>'

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute(SQL)

cur.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyodbc
server = 'SERVIDORNOMEOUIP'
database = 'MEUBANCO'
username = 'USERSQL'
password = 'SENHASQL'

#for SQL Server 2008
driver='{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password + ';')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT nome,senha FROM [tabusuariosenha]")

row = cursor.fetchone()
print ("CAMPO1  |  CAMPO2 " )
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```