# send data fro linux/python to sql server/windows

Tags: c#, python, sql-server

I have raspberry pi 3 that gets me data from sensors by using Python.
I want to send that data to a windows pc and precisely to the SQL server.
I knew that the best choice I have is to use the httprequest method or get/post.
Any help concerning the code of the service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct queries from your python application gathering data to send it to your SQL Server - it doesn't matter if the SQL Server is running on Widows or Linux. If you want to send it via HTTP Request, you will need to write second application - API to process the request and save data to SQL Server.
In that case see the link below.

[Connecting python 3.3 to microsoft sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411362/connecting-python-3-3-to-microsoft-sql-server-2008)

[Connecting to Microsoft SQL server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725862/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-python)

[GitHub of pyodbc library](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows)

```
import pyodbc 
db = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 13.0};"
                  "Server=server_name;"
                  "Database=db_name;"
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                  "uid=username;"
                  "pwd=password";)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('some SQL query')
```

Comment: I am using Python 3 in the RPi 3 and SQL server 17

Comment: pymysql is just for MYsql

Comment: @MHDBKT I am aware of that - it was just an example, as I wrote it.